# Mapping symbols and special characters to home row in insert mode

Tags: keyboard-layout

Typing symbol is difficult, so I wish to to map those symbol on number keys to home row by a prefix key like <kbd>,</kbd>. It is the idea from workman dead mode keyboard layout, by pressing <kbd>,</kbd> and the keyboard enter symbol mode the input of normal keys is changed to symbol
[image]

But I find this provided layout is not easy to type, like combination of <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> to make `-` is not easy to reach.

I would like to make a new table, will there be any good idea to map a even more typer-friendly symbol layout?

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I  have slightly reformat your question to make it less ambiguous for me. Don't hesitate to rechange it if I have twisted it.

Comment: What remain unclear to me is how to input `,`?

Comment: input <,> is easy press<,> and space, as space is usually leave after a comma

Comment: I believe `,` is a good prefix choice since it is used as <leader> by a number of users but as for the layout I suppose it is very opinion based.

Comment: The possibility to configure Vim is certainly one of its strong points and a reason it enjoys such popularity. I think trying to improve it is a noble endeavor. However, asking for a better layout is highly subjective. Don't get me wrong: it's a good idea but a bad question for this site. I would suggest that you create a mapping that works for you and then share it as a plugin.

Comment: Welcome vi.SE :) For me, it's a system level problem (otherwise your nice layout won't be useful outside of vim, for example when replying with your web browser.) However, if you want to go that way, you can re-map (or I'll use abbreviations)

Comment: For completeness one could mention plugins like [vim-submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode) but I agree with gildux. Years ago I have spent a significant amount of time trying to find a good solution to your problem using vim-only solution... My conclusion is that using a programmable keyboard which can have its layers configured is the easy and most flexible option.

Comment: Yes, back to the same question, I try karabiner element to add layers on my macbook keyboard, I now held down space key to active symbol layer, while, I still find the idea of dead key worth it, although I still don't know how to implement it